# How do I always get synchronous execution function with a use deferred object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jquery-deferred, deferred, deferred-execution

In my task I want to wait for an asynchronous execution of the function and only then output the result. 
How can I do this, if my attempts in the code do not work?

```
    CanPrintVS(): boolean {
        var result = false;
```

> // at this point I want to wait for the synchronous execution function
>   CheckRefLink :

```
        $.when(this.CheckRefLink().then((r: boolean) => { result = r; }));
        return result;
    }

    private CheckRefLink() {
        var def = $.Deferred();
        if (this.DOC_RC.KIND_DOC == 3) {
            var reflinks = this.DOC_RC.REF_LINK_List;

            var waitRefs = $.Deferred();
```

> // 1) In the first case - just a resolve value:

```
            if (reflinks)
                waitRefs.resolve(reflinks);
```

> //2) or wait for execution:

```
            else
                ds.loadT({ REF_LINK: criteries({ISN_REF_DOC: this.ISN_DOC})
            }).promise().then(r => { waitRefs.resolve(r.result); });

            waitRefs.done((ns) => {
                    var linkcl = dm.LINK_CL[ns.ISN_CLLINK];
                    return def.resolve(linkcl && linkcl.LINK_DIR == 1);
            });
        }
        return def.resolve(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot do that. The APIs you are using are asynchronous.

Comment: No. I use a deferred objects, which are also described on this page. But it not work.